# Interactive page in tableau

Tags: r, user-interface, user-input, tableau-api, data-analysis

I am building a BI application

Data Source: Excel file and Microsoft Database
Data Analysis: R
Data Reporting: Tableau Public

My use case is to take 5-6 inputs from the user. Inputs will in like a drop down and multiple selection box. Based on the inputs I need to do the analysis and display it on Tableau.

Question:

1. How to take user inputs in tableau? like a form? Or what is a alternative for taking user inputs and pass it to Tableau/R?
2. If I think of making an Web page then how to pass value from page to R and Tableau and return the analysis back to web page?

Please provide you valuable inputs or some alternative to achieve my requirements.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For my use case I am avoiding Tableau due to time constraint, and will be using RStudio for integrating the data and doing the analysis. For the user input and visualization part I will be using Shiny by RStudio ( http://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/ ). Do check their website.

In future if I find some solution with Tableau then will surely post in here.

Thanks for all the suport.

Comment: ...so your question was "how to do this in Tableau (with R)", and your answer was "don't use Tableau." Maybe next time you ask a question you could be more clear about your requirements.

Comment: Ya. I thought to use tableau because of it userInterface and easy visual reports but couldn't find a way to achieve it. So, I found this alternative due to time constraint with my assignment.
Next time will be more clear with my queries.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create parameters, and set them on the sheet, so the user can input values there.

http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/using-parameters

2. Depending on what you're doing, you can use Tableau connection with R. Pretty simple to use, but does not cover everything R can do

http://www.tableausoftware.com/new-features/r-integration
http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/r-implementation-notes

Comment: Thank you for the input. 
Now the problem is:
1. I will have dropdown for user to select a value and a multiple selection box for user to select multiple values. So, I think this solution wont work. Could you please suggest some alternative or best solution to achieve my goals? Thank you in advance.